# How do you install an iOS framework? I am getting 'LRResty/LRResty.h' file not found

Tags: ios, frameworks

I am trying to install LRResty from http://projects.lukeredpath.co.uk/resty/getting-started.html.

These are the steps which I have taken:

1. Checked out the source from github
2. I dragged 'LRResty.xcodeproj' to my project in XCode
3. I added ObjC and all_load linker flags
4. Then I added #import to AppDelegate.h

At this point I tried building but I was getting 'LRResty/LRResty.h' file not found

1. I also tried adding the following: LRResty to Target Dependency.

However, I am not able to get this to work. Any ideas?

Screenshot: http://imgur.com/RVAAB

Comment: The link says "Resty is distributed as a static framework for iOS and Mac". Did you try copying the static library instead of the project?

Comment: @Vin by "static library" do you mean the root of the git clone folder, LRResty, which contains Classes, Documentation, Examples... ?

Comment: I think Proteas has already answered the question comprehensively.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think: 
    You should download and install the framework according to their doc, and try to compile your project.
    According to the doc, you can build the project to a framework, then use that you just build.
    If you want just dragging it to your project, you should edit their and your project settings for:1.build their to a static lib, export header files. 2.make your project linking the static lib ,finding the header files, and maybe their project has resoures like images, you should copy them to your project. it is so complex.

the best way is: download the code, build the project to a framework, the drag the framework to your target project.

If you want to consume a rest style web service , RestKit is also a choise:http://restkit.org/